# Formula to return random string from list of strings?

Tags: random, formula, openoffice-calc

I want to display random courses (`MBA`, `MSc`) in OpenOffice Calc. I tried:

```
=RANDBETWEEN('MBA', 'MSc')
```

and

```
=RAND('MBA', 'MSc')`
```

but they don't work as desired.

Comment: This is an useful question, but it fits better on http://superuser.com. Please don't delete the question, i expect it will get moved there by the admins soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In OpenOffice Calc, the **[`RAND` function](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_RAND_function)** returns a value between 0 and 1 - so you will have to combine different formulas to get a random selection from two text values. The following steps are needed:

- round the result of rand to an integer;
- based on that integer, select from list.

Try the following formula:

```
=CHOOSE(ROUND(RAND()+1);"MBA";"MSc")
```

or split up on different lines:

```
=CHOOSE(
    ROUND(
        RAND()+1
    );
    "MBA";
    "MSc"
)
```

*Depending on you localization, you max have to replace the argument separators `;` by `:`.*

Explanation:

- the **[`CHOOSE` formula](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_CHOOSE_function)** chooses from a list of values; the selection is based on the first argument (here: the rounded random value);
- the **[`ROUND` formula](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_ROUND_function)** rounds the decimal to integer;
- [**`RAND()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_RAND_function) **`+ 1`** makes sure that the resulting random value is either `1` or `2`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a user with a deep understanding of spreadsheets, but I thought this was an interesting question. I wanted to play around with an example with more than two choices and  tried an exercise with six choices.

The OpenOffice wiki for the RAND function says...

```
RAND()*(b-a) + a

returns a random real number between a and b.
```

Since the CHOOSE function needed integers 1 to 6 to make the 6 choices, RAND would need to output numbers from 1 to 6, I let a=1 and b=6.

This was tested,

```
=CHOOSE(ROUND(5*RAND()+1);"Business";"Science";"Art";"History";"Math";"Law")
```

That output a random selection of the six courses, but I found the six choices did not have equal chances of selection. Business and Law had a 1 in 10 chance of being selected and Science, Art, History, and Math had a 2 in 10 chance of being selected.

```
=CHOOSE(ROUNDUP(6*RAND()+0.00001);"Business";"Science";"Art";"History";"Math";"Law")
```

Seems to give all six courses a practically equal chance for selection.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, came across this requirement today. Modified the accepted answer to handle the number of choices more than 2

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1;3);"MBA";"MSc";"MCom")
```

The second argument to RANDBETWEEN being the number of values in the list.